# Deploy React/Webpack static directory on different server from index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'd like to deploy a React app built with create-react-app within my company's CMS. I can't host assets on the CMS, just the script tag, css tag and root DIV. I've deployed the static assets to S3 and pointed my publicPath to AWS, but in my CSS the components are not rendered. I'm new to webpack configuration and unsure where to turn.

Comment: Did you set : https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#user-content-outputpublicpath ?

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways where to build assets for deploy:

- build assets on local machine and deploy static files
- deploy sources to server and perform assets building there

There are some differences. For example first way may require more data to transfer, and second way requires more complicated configuration on server. Server must have possibility to execute different tools including webpack and have enough place for node modules.